# How to Use EF 5 Include With Tables Mapped with Unique Constraint?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have 2 tables,

```
Application
ID  varchar(50)
Version varchar(50)

Page
ID          int 
ApplicationVersion  varchar(50)
```

They are joined with Version instead of ID. Can I use EF 5 Include to Load respected entities? This is not working for me.

```
context.Pages.Where(p => p.ID == id).Include(p => p.Application).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: do you have a FK linking the two tables together?

Comment: Yes in the Database and in code, In SQl Profiler it shows that it joins (Application)ID with ApplicationVersion
            this.HasRequired(t => t.Application)
                .WithMany(t => t.Pages)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.ApplicationVersion);

Comment: what do you mean by 'not working'?

Comment: @Phil, Not working means Page.Application is null

Comment: It seems to work OK for me using database first.  It looks like you're using code first.